The keyboard and touchpad do not work on the laptop after installing Ubuntu 24.04
Once the installation of Ubuntu 24.04 Lts was finished on a Samsung Ultra book 900X3D, the keyboard and touch pad mouse stopped working, it only accepts USB, it seems to me it is a driver issue
